# Is it possible to emit a custom event from a nested child component, and capture it at the parent component in Stencil.js?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I have a `dropdown` component, inside, I nest a `dropdown-menu` component, and inside the `dropdown-menu`, I nest `dropdown-item` component.

```
<ifx-dropdown>
  <ifx-dropdown-menu>
    <ifx-dropdown-item>Menu Item</ifx-dropdown-item>
    <ifx-dropdown-item>Menu Item</ifx-dropdown-item>
    <ifx-dropdown-item>Menu Item</ifx-dropdown-item>
    <ifx-dropdown-item>Menu Item</ifx-dropdown-item>
    <ifx-dropdown-item>Menu Item</ifx-dropdown-item>
  </ifx-dropdown-menu>
</ifx-dropdown>
```

When you select an item from the menu list, i.e. click a `dropdown-item` component, an event is emitted, which is captured inside `dropdown-menu` component. I want to instead capture it at the `dropdown` parent level, but it's not working. Nothing is being captured.

ChatGPT suggested that you can't capture events at the parent component if they're emitted from a nested child component using slots.

Could anyone confirm/deny if this is really the case?

Note that I can capture it at the parent but only if I listen to the document instead.

```
@Listen('customEvent', { target: 'document' })
```

I don't want to listen to the document, because this could cause issues if multiple instances exists of the same component.

Comment: You have to set ``composed:true`` on the Custom Event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed for Events to 'escape' shadowRoots

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I did, but still not capturing it. `@Event({composed: true}) ifxDropdownItem: EventEmitter;`

Comment: Have you read those docs??? ``bubbles:true`` is required too.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Well, it's still not working.. any other ideas? Also, are you sure it's supposed to work?

Comment: Even if I emit from the dropdown-menu, which is the first direct child element nested inside dropdown, it's still not being captured in the dropdown. Nothing is captured in the parent dropdown.

Comment: The issue was something else. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: So ChatGPT was wrong?

Comment: @G.Tranter Hard to say, since the issue was with my code, so chat GPT suggested that if my code is perfectly fine, then it could be because of the slots. But yeah, maybe he was wrong to say it.